# Fresh Install Unbuntu Server - Stops - last line "SATA link down"

Tags: usb-installation

please forgive me I am a noob.

I flashed **ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso** onto USB drive and am installing that onto a new machine.

Nothing happens; afaik the installer doesn't start. See image attached. What should I do? [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIXof.jpg)